# What component could be

Tags: identification, components, telephone, telecommunications

I have a VDSL telephony socket with some electronics in it. I reverse engineered the PCB, but there is one component I cannot identify at all. Look like a 0.25W TH resistor, light-blue body and a single red ring as marking. On the PCB is identified as T1 (but definitely not a transistor ;) ).

This how it looks like (the small blue guy, sry I can't zoom in more):[image]
I also add the schematics (reverse-engineered after the PCB). The component in question is T1 (this is a simmetrical design, so no sense what is doing there):
[image]

Comment: Show us a picture. T never refers to a transistor (that would be Q).

Comment: Yup, done! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a single black stripe then it's a zero-Ohm resistor (a.k.a. jumper). Remember the resistor colour stripe codes: Black is zero.

<sup>Don't ask what that jumper does there.</sup>

Comment: Could it be taking the place of a timed fuse?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah, could be a replacement for a fuse or bead or something else. Maybe it's just a jumper to to run a trace over another trace (common on single-side board designs).

Comment: I updated with schematics...

Comment: The measurable resistance is 1 ohm

Comment: @ZoltánGógucz That's to be suspected from a normal DMM. The zero ohm resistor is not superconducting either, but hopefully less than 1 ohm.

Comment: @ZoltánGógucz That's the total resistance of the supposedly-zero resistor and the lead resistance (i.e. the resistance you measure when you short the leads).

Answer (score 1):

Mistery resolved! That component is used as a simple jumper wire because on the solder side of the PCB there is a trace crossing between the terminals.
Thank you all for your contribution!